# Not able to connect to Snowflake from EMR Cluster using Pyspark using airflow emr operator

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, airflow, amazon-emr

I am trying to connect to snowflake from EMR cluster launched by airflow EMR operator but I'm getting the following error

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> o147.load. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data
> source: net.snowflake.spark.snowflake. Please find packages at
> http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

These are the steps I am adding to my EMRaddsteps operator to run the script `load_updates.py` and I am describing my snowflake packages in the "**Args**"

```
STEPS = [
    {
        "Name" : "convo_facts",
        "ActionOnFailure" : "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
        "HadoopJarStep" : {
            "Jar" : "command-runner.jar",
            "Args" : ["spark-submit", "s3://dev-data-lake/spark_files/cf/load_updates.py", \
                      "--packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.8.0,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.4.14-spark_2.4", \
                      "INPUT=s3://dev-data-lake/table_exports/public/", \
                      "OUTPUT=s3://dev-data-lake/emr_output/cf/"]
        }
    }
]

JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
    'Name' : 'cftest',
    'LogUri' : 's3://dev-data-lake/emr_logs/cf/log.txt',
    'ReleaseLabel' : 'emr-5.32.0',
    'Instances' : {
        'InstanceGroups' : [
            {
                'Name' : 'Master nodes',
                'Market' : 'ON_DEMAND',
                'InstanceRole' : 'MASTER',
                'InstanceType' : 'r6g.4xlarge',
                'InstanceCount' : 1,
            },
            {
                'Name' : 'Slave nodes',
                'Market' : 'ON_DEMAND',
                'InstanceRole' : 'CORE',
                'InstanceType' : 'r6g.4xlarge',
                'InstanceCount' : 3,
            }
        ],
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps' : True,
        'TerminationProtected' : False
    },
    'Applications' : [{
        'Name' : 'Spark'
    }],
    'JobFlowRole' : 'EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
    'ServiceRole' : 'EMR_DefaultRole'
}
```

And, this is how I am adding snowflake creds in my load_updates.py script to extract into a pyspark dataframe.

```
# Set options below
sfOptions = {
  "sfURL" : "xxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com",
  "sfUser" : "user",
  "sfPassword" : "xxxx",
  "sfDatabase" : "",
  "sfSchema" : "PUBLIC",
  "sfWarehouse" : ""
}

SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

query_sql = """select * from cf""";

messages_new = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
  .options(**sfOptions) \
  .option("query", query_sql) \
  .load()
```

Not sure if I am missing something here or where am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `--package` should be placed before `s3://.../load_updates.py` in the spark-submit command. Otherwise, it'll be considered as application argument.

Try with this :

```py
STEPS = [
    {
        "Name": "convo_facts",
        "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
        "HadoopJarStep": {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args": [
                "spark-submit",
                "--packages",
                "net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.8.0,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.4.14-spark_2.4",
                "s3://dev-data-lake/spark_files/cf/load_updates.py",
                "INPUT=s3://dev-data-lake/table_exports/public/",
                "OUTPUT=s3://dev-data-lake/emr_output/cf/"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: your answer is working and thank you so much for it. I am also writing data from EMR to a snowflake table and I can see that happening but it is taking almost 1 hour for the data transfer from EMR to snowflake or s3 too. Wondering if you experienced a similar situation and if so how did you face it? The compute part takes hardly 3-5 min.